# Regular Expression matching Sentence that MAY contain Parantheses

Tags: regex

Am using this expression in REGEX to capture words being sent to our data quality systems. This should be a FULL match - ie all the words in a sentence:
`(^$|^\w+(\s\w+)*$)`

This works for all scenarios like this:

```
A sheep jumped over a fence
```

But not for this

```
A sheep jumped over a fence (And Tripped)
```

I understand that `\w` takes care of only alphanumeric and underscore. But I would also want this to match sentences with the Brackets `(` `)` like in the example above. Is there a way to achieve this to ADDITIONALLY add the `(` `)` checks so both scenarios can be satisfied?

Comment: Do you need to validate what is inside parentheses? If not, `^(?:(?:\w+|\([^()]*\))(?:\s(?:\w+|\([^()]*\)))*)?$`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CxCz0x/1).

Comment: thanks. no i dont need to validate BUT it can have an opening paranthesis and not closing like this `A sheep jumped over a fence (And Tripped`

Comment: 1) `^\(?\w+\)?(\s\(?\w+\)?)*$`? or 2) `^[\w()]+(\s[\w()]+)*$`

Comment: I might be misunderstanding this (always take whatever Wiktor says over anybody else) but maybe you are looking for something simple to match each word like this? `^$|([\w]+)` or a full match like this `^$|([ \w()]+)`

Comment: @sniperd Or even simpler: `^[\s\w()]*$`

Comment: @sniperd  this is even more succint. And it works Please add to the main answer so I can mark it as official answer

Comment: @anubhava yours is even more succint. works beautifully thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding this (always take whatever Wiktor says over anybody else) but maybe you are looking for something simple to match each word like this?

`^$|([\w]+)`

or a full match like this

`^$|([ \w()]+)`

Good luck!  A good place to try this stuff out is at https://regex101.com/ :)  What is neat with regexes is you can make them really clever and small, but I lean towards the side of being able to read easily later.  Use whichever one gets it done and is easy to understand.